# jquery - select an element with specific content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-selectors

I have an html structure like this:

```
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">1</span>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">2</span>
</div>
...
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">100</span>
</div>
```

In my javascript code, I need to **get an `<span>` element with class `content` that has exactly `1` or `2` , ..., `100`**

I tested jquery [`.contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) method, **but this returns all elements that have for example `1`. such as `1`, `12`, ...**.

Comment: First, there is no span element with class `test`. Second `...` is a text node and is not wrapped under any element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter` method which accepts a callback function applied to every item.

```js
var array=$('.test').find('.content').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().trim()==100;
});
console.log(Array.from(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">1</span>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">2</span>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">100</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `.html` use `.text`.

Comment: @Rajesh It really depends. In this case with respect to the question, both are functionally interchangeable.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Thank you for your perfect answer.

Comment: @Terry In my understanding, we create a sample for SO but our actual code is way different. Hence I'd prefer using `.text` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed in the following manner:

```js
$('.content').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == "2")
  {
    console.log("THE SPAN WITH 2 IS ");
    console.log($(this)[0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">1</span>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">2</span>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">100</span>
</div>
```

What we do here is check through the content class of the spans and check if their inner html is 2 and if it is we console.log it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vanilla **.indexOf()** method.

The indexOf method takes a parameter of the string you want to find and returns either the index (if it's found), or **-1** if it's not.

```
var myEl = document.querySelector(".test"):

for loop...

if( myEl.innerHTML.indexOf(2) != -1 ){
    console.log("This element contains the number 2")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`, get and check `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` of element, at `.filter()` callback you can use `RegExp` `N$` where `N` is number to match. For example, to match elements having `"1"` or `"2"` set at `.textContent` you can use `RegExp` `/1$|2$/`; to match `"100"`, `/100$/`; with `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```js
var filtered = $("span.content").filter((_, {textContent}) => 
                 /1$|2$/.test(textContent));

filtered.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">1</span>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">2</span>
</div>
...
<div class="test">
   <span class="content">100</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this..

```
$('.test').each(function() {

if($(this).text == '1')
{
var a = $(this).html();
}

});
```

a will now contain the html of that span which contains your text.